# Show that $\{a\in k\mid k\models\phi(a)\}$ is finite or cofinite

Tags: logic, solution-verification

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $\phi(v)$ an $L=L_{\text{rings}}$-formula in one free variable $v$. Prove that the set $A = \{a\in k\mid k\models \phi(a)\}$ is either finite or cofinite.

**My attempt:**

The field $k$ is a model of the theory of algebraically closed fields $T=T_{\text{acf}}$, which admits quantifier elimination (Tarski). This implies that all $L$-formulas are composed of connectives ($\wedge,\vee,\to,\neg$) of atomic formulas of the form $t=s$. In particular $(t=s)(a,\vec{b})$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ (since $L$ contains $0, 1, +, \cdot$). Therefore $$k\models (t=s)(a,\vec{b}) \iff P(a,\vec{b})=0$$ for some polynomial $P$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. So, $\phi(v) \equiv (P_1(v)=0 \wedge P_2(v) = 0 \wedge \dots \wedge P_l(v)= 0\wedge Q(v)\ne 0)$, where I used that $k$ is a field so $r_1\ne 0 \wedge \dots r_k\ne 0 \iff r_1\cdots r_k\ne 0$.

We have $k\models \phi(a)$ if $a$ is a root of a finite number of polynomials, meaning that $A$ is  at most finite. How do I get cofinite?

Thanks.

Comment: What if $\phi(x) \equiv  x \neq 0$?

Comment: The field $k$ is algebraically closed, therefore infinite. If $\phi(x)\equiv x\ne 0$, then $k\models \phi(a)$ when $a\ne 0$, making $A$ infinite ($|A|=|k|-1 = |k|$).

Comment: So you have an example where the set is cofinite. You need to refine your approach. Putting the QF formula into DNF will help: